# SCSS Mixin Error: expected a variable name (e.g. $x)

Tags: css, sass

I get this error:

```
While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
   /client/stylesheets/main.scss: Scss compiler error: expected a variable name (e.g. $x)
   or ')' for the parameter list for pos-abs
```

---

This is my `@mixin`:

***_mixins.scss:***

```
@mixin pos-abs ($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
  position: absolute;
  top: percentage($top + 'px' / $h);
  right: percentage($right + 'px' / $w);
  bottom: percentage($bottom + 'px' / $h);
  left: percentage($left + 'px' / $w);
};
```

---

This is how I call `@mixin`:

***_foo.scss:***

```
@mixin pos-abs(0, 313, 0, 12);
```

---

This is where I declared `vars`:

***_sizes.scss:***

```
$w: 375px;
$h: 662px;
```

---

This is my file load order:

***main.scss:***

```
@import "sizes";
@import "mixins";
@import "foo";
```

---

P.S. If I remove *$h* & *$w* `vars` and hardcode them in the `@mixin` `(e.g. top: percentage($top + 'px' / 662px); )` -- I get the same error. If I remove all `+ 'px'` from my `@mixin` and pass `args` to the mixin like: `@mixin pos-abs(0px, 313px, 0px, 12px);` -- the error persists.

***Where is my mistake?***

Comment: I haven't used Sass/SCSS much but shouldn't you be using `@include` for mixin call instead of `@mixin`. And even after that you may end up with problem in the percentage function because when you append `px` to a number, it would become a string and math operations won't work on it. You should try using `$top * 1px / $h` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

The way you are calling the mixin seems to be wrong. The correct way would be to call it as follows:

```
@include [mixin-name]([mixin-params]);
```

When you write `@mixin pos-abs...`, the compiler seems to be expecting (and rightly so) a variable to follow the mixin name as that is a mixin definition statement and hence the error states that it expects a variable or a closing parenthesis to follow the opening parenthesis.

---

**Problem 2:**

Even after resolving that error, you'd still run into a problem with the `percentage` function. In that, you are appending the `px` via string concatenation to the number and this would make the whole value to be cast as a string instead of a number. This means any math operations on it would fail.

You should instead multiply the number with `1px`  or add `0px`. This would not only add the units to the value but would also make it a number.

```
$w: 375px;
$h: 662px;

@mixin pos-abs ($top, $right, $bottom, $left) {
  position: absolute;
  top: percentage($top * 1px / $h);
  right: percentage($right * 1px / $w);
  bottom: percentage($bottom * 1px  / $h);
  left: percentage($left * 1px / $w);
};

#demo{
  @include pos-abs(0, 313, 0, 12);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! `@include` -- this s my silly error :)).  Thanks for **Problem 2** solving.